# Connected subgroups of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: reference-request, connectedness, topological-groups

I was reading this [first look at differential algebra](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehubbard/diffalg1.pdf), when I came across to the following result:

any proper connected **complex** subgroup of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is conjugate to one of the following subgroups:

$\{ I_2\}, \pmatrix{a & 0 \cr 0 & a^{-1}}, a\in\mathbb{C}^\times, \pmatrix{1 & b \cr 0 & 1}, b\in\mathbb{C},\pmatrix{a & b \cr 0 & a^{-1}}, a\in\mathbb{C}^\times,b\in\mathbb{C}. $

There is no proof or reference given in the pdf, so I guess it is well-known from specialists and/or easy.

I can see why these guys are connected. I can also see why a connected subgroup, after conjugation if needed, would contain a matrix of one the previous four shapes, but that's it...

If I had to prove it myself, my first try would be to use the exponential map to reduce to finding connected complex  subgroups of the additive group of matrices with trace zero, which is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^3$, but I don't know how to do it.

Can someone give a reference, or even better, arguments to get this result ? Elementary arguments are particularly appreciated (if one could avoid the theory of Lie groups, it would be great).

**Edit.** Even if this is not mentionned in the paper, the connected subgroups are supposed to be complex subgroups. Otherwise,the list above is incomplete (see  comments).

Comment: That list is not complete. For example, there is also $\left\{\pmatrix{a & 0 \cr 0 & a^{-1}} \biggm| a\in\mathbb{R}^\times\right\}$.

Comment: AH...This is problematic. Is the complete list known ? Besides, do you know how to prove Thm 4 of the pdf, then ?

Comment: They surely mean **complex** subgroups. Then the list is correct.

Comment: Thanks! By "complex subgroup", you mean algebraic subgroup over $\mathbb{C}$, right ? Do you have any reference/proof that this list is complete in this case?

Comment: In this case, it is equivalent to what I meant. But I meant complex Lie subgroups. I am sure this was asked at MSE before. The easiest way to prove it is to classify complex Lie subalgebras in $sl(2,C)$.

Comment: @GreginGre complex subgroup means it's also a holomorphic submanifold. Here it makes no difference but I'm not sure in general whether a complex connected subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{C})$ is always Zariski-closed.